# Can we always define the projection in a ball of raius $R$ for any Polish metric space $X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, projection

I'm generalizing some theorems to Polish metric spaces, which were originally proved for $\mathbb R^n$. Hence, as I'm adapting the proofs, I'm checking whether where I can reuse the same arguments. In one of my proofs, I had the following:

"Define $\pi_R : \mathbb R^n \to B(R)$ to be the projection operator on the closed ball with radius $R$ and centered at zero".

Now I'd like to use this for an $X$ metric Polish space. Can I "safely" assume that there exists such projection operator $\pi_R: X \to B(R)$ such that the closed ball is centered at some
$x_0 \in X$? How can I know that this map is well defined?

Comment: When you say a "projection", what do you mean? Are you talking about a metric projection?

Comment: Sorry, you mean the argmin, right? Surely your projection isn't real valued!

Comment: I mean $\pi_R(y):= arg\min_{x \in B(R)} d(x,y)$ for the Euclidean space with the ball centered at 0.

Comment: There are Polish spaces $X$, $x\in X$ and $r>0$ such that there is *no* continuous retraction of $X$ on the closed ball of radius $r$ around $x$ regardless of how you define them

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was fixing it.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, I see, so perhaps I cannot use the argument with the closed ball.

Comment: You can retract $X$ on $B_r(x)$ whenever $B_r(x)$ embeds as a convex subspace in a locally convex metrizable topological vector space, which is not a good criterion to work with, but it gives some more Polish spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no". Consider the separable real Banach space $\ell^2$. Any closed subspace of $\ell^2$ is Polish, a fact we shall soon use.

Let $e_n$ be the $n$th basis vector, i.e. $e_n$ is the sequence such that the $n$th entry in the sequence is $1$, while the other entries are $0$. Let
$$C = \left\{\frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{4}e_{n+1} : n \ge 1\right\}$$
and
$$X = C \cup \{2e_1\}.$$
Note that every point in $X$ is isolated, and hence $X \subseteq \ell^2$ is closed, and hence a Polish space in its own right. If we have distinct $\frac{n + 1}{2n} e_n$ and $\frac{m + 1}{2m} e_m$ in $C$, then
$$\left\|\frac{n + 1}{4n} e_n - \frac{m + 1}{4m} e_m\right\|^2 = \left(\frac{n + 1}{4n}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{m + 1}{4m}\right)^2 \le \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1,$$
but
$$\left\|\frac{n + 1}{4n} e_n - 2e_1\right\|^2 = \left(\frac{n + 1}{4n}\right)^2 + 4 \ge 4.$$
Therefore, $C$ is the closed unit ball in $X$, centred at any point in $C$. We can now show that $2e_1$ has no closest point, i.e. the projection map simply does not extend to this point in $X$. We see that

$$\left\|\frac{n + 1}{4n} e_n - 2e_1\right\|^2 = \left(\frac{n + 1}{4n}\right)^2 + 4  \to \frac{17}{4},$$

while remaining strictly greater than $\frac{17}{4}$ for every $n \ge 2$. Therefore, there is no point in $C$ that achieves the infimal distance of $\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}$ to any unit ball centred in $C$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $X=C\cup\{2e_1\}$? Because $2e_1$ is not in $X$ as written

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I did, thanks.